# Changing variable `payloadmod=digital.constellation_qpsk()` at runtime in GNU Radio with XMLRPC Server block support

Tags: python, gnuradio, xmlrpclib, gnuradio-companion

I have a problem changing the `payloadmod` variable in GNURadio. I am running GNURadio remotely and changing variables at runtime, which is supported by the XMLRPC Server block.

First of all, I can easily change `freq`, `packetlen`, `bandwidth`, `ipaddress`, `gain`, etc., variables in a runtime scenario remotely with a variation of the following XML:  (making sure to specify `set_` before each variable name)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall><methodName>set_bandwidth</methodName><params><param><value><int>200000</int></value></param></params></methodCall>
```

However, I am having issues with the `set_payloadmod` variable.

In gnuradio-companion, I have the following variable set:

```
id=payloadmod
value=digital.constellation_qpsk()
```

I send the following XML to change the `payloadmod` variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall><methodName>set_payloadmod</methodName><params><param><value><string>digital.constellation_bpsk()</string></value></param></params></methodCall>
```

And I get the following error.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
<fault>
<value><struct>
<member>
<name>faultCode</name>
<value><int>1</int></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>faultString</name>
<value><string>&lt;type 'exceptions.AttributeError'&gt;:'str' object has no attribute 'bits_per_symbol'</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value>
</fault>
</methodResponse>
```

It does not like the XML string tag. I have tried changing the XML tag to the following without success:

```
<int>digital.constellation_bpsk()</int>
<value>digital.constellation_bpsk()</value>
<any>digital.constellation_bpsk()</any>
```

In gnuradio-companion, I have also tried creating two variable as follows:

```
id=payloadmodfrnt
value=‘digital.constellation_qpsk()’

id=payloadmod
value=eval(str(payloadmodfrnt).replace("'",""))
```

The `eval(str(……).replace("'","")` in payloadmod variable will remove the single quote from the payloadmodfrnt variable string passed in with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall><methodName>set_payloadmodfrnt</methodName><params><param><value><string>digital.constellation_bpsk()</string></value></param></params></methodCall>
```

The variable changes in both `payloadmodfrnt` and `payloadmod` (which is viewable in the GUI). However, the payloadmod variable does not change to bpsk. It will continue to transmit qpsk and not bpsk (I can see  the constellation has not changed on the receiver).

Return/enter or something needs to be pressed or something. Basically the payload variable needs to be kicked or something to make it change. Or (the simplest option), I need the right XML tags to change the payloadmod variable correctly?

Comment: The grc files used are just modified versions of the tx_ofdm.grc and rx_ofdm.grc located in the GNU Radio examples: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/tree/master/gr-digital/examples/ofdm